# Code in bash creates infinite loops when checking two conditions

Tags: bash, file, while-loop, user-input, infinite-loop

So I'm very new to bash and still trying to understand the basics of it. Currently I am working on a simple photo manager script that will ask the user to input a number which will then create a file called pic.photo. However before creating the file there is two conditions that must be met; 1. The number must be in range from 1 to 99999 and 2. the file must not exist already. Down below is my code.

```
while [[ true ]]; do

    while [[ true ]]; do
        read -p "Enter Photo Number: " photoNum
        if [[ $photoNum -ge 1 && $photoNum -le 99999 ]]; then break; fi
            echo "Photo Number is not in the range 1 to 99999";   
        done

    fileNum=p${photoNum}.photo

    while [[ true ]]; do
        if [[ -f "$fileNum" ]]; then break; fi
            echo "p$photoNum.photo already exists"; 
        done
done

touch data/p$photoNum.photo
```

If anyone could provide feedback, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Things to improve:

1. Test for the existence of the right file. The test checks for the
   file in the current directory even though you are putting them on
   the "data" directory.
2. Be consistent about wrapping your variables in curly brackets. It's recommended that you do wrap all variables to avoid unintended
   expansions. And it also makes it easy to use parameter expansion
   operations.
3. I think that the control structure needs to be simpler. Not only to
   make it more readable but to make it easy to understand. The nested
   While loops are all doing things that can be accomplished with just
   one loop and the right if-then statements.
4. The `touch` command is never reached because it is outside of the loop.
5. You can make your question better by asking a clear question and posting the error or, in this case, the line where your loop gets stuck.

The following code modifies the behavior that stopped the program if the conditions were not met. Now the user is asked to input a new number right after. I did this based on the interpretation that you wanted to use the while loop for this purpose. Otherwise, there is little reason to use a while statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

while [[ true ]]; do
        read -p "Enter Photo Number: " photoNum
        if ! [[ ${photoNum} -ge 1 && ${photoNum} -le 99999 ]]; then
            echo "Photo Number is not in the range 1 to 99999"
            continue
        fi
        fileNum=p${photoNum}.photo
        if [[ -f data/"${fileNum}" ]]; then
            echo "p${photoNum}.photo already exists"
            continue
        else
            touch data/p${photoNum}.photo
        fi
done
```

As a final tip, if you want to look under the hood during runtime use `set -x` in your code below the interpreter line. uncomment the second line from the provided code to try it out.